# Is it possible to allow TIME / DATE RESTRICTED visitor access to a certain page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

So I know how to give a certain user access to a certain modern SharePoint page, but is it possible to set a time (date) restriction to that access, or do I have to remember to remove the permission later on to stop access?

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

As a workaround you can try below approach:

1. Create a manually triggered Power Automate flow which will grant necessary permissions to user.
2. Then pause the flow for specific time/date.
3. Revoke assigned permissions for user

Below references will help you to get started with building such flow:

1. [Using Flow to grant access in SharePoint](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/using-Flow-to-grant-access-in-SharePoint/td-p/332314)
2. [Pause a Flow using Delay and Delay Until | Power Automate](https://d365demystified.com/2020/06/17/pause-a-flow-using-delay-and-delay-until-power-automate/)